# How to fix : "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

before I start, I'd like to say that i've seen the page with the same problem as I have. But for some reason i can't figure out where my problem is. 
I'm fairly new to programming so sorry if I made any major mistakes in the program. I'll explain my problem: everytime I run the code the game actually works but after a while a long text appears in my terminal which says: "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message". I know it probably has something to do with the message.delete code but I'm not able to fix it.

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});


let word;
let letter;
let lWord = [];
let charLength;
let txt = [];
let outputTxt;
let misscount;
let misses = 0;
let succes;


bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);
    bot.user.setActivity("Hangman with y'all");
});


bot.on("message", async message => { 
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];


    if(cmd === `${prefix}word`){                                        
        word = messageArray[1];
        message.delete(100);
        console.log("\x1b[33m", "Word has been set to: " + word);
        console.log("\x1b[0m");
        startGame();
    }


    else if(cmd === `${prefix}reset`){
        console.log("\x1b[34m", "Player has reset the game");
        console.log("\x1b[0m");
        reset();
    }


    else if(cmd === `${prefix}letter`){
        letter = messageArray[1];
        console.log("\x1b[36m", "Entered letter was: " + letter);
        console.log("\x1b[0m")
        tryletter();
    }


    function startGame(){
        lWord = word.split("");
        charLength = lWord.length;

        for(i = 0; i<charLength; i++) { 
            txt[i] = "?"
          }

        outputTxt = txt.join(" ");
        txtOutput();
    }


    function txtOutput(){
        return message.channel.send(outputTxt);
    }


    function tryletter() {
        misscount = 0;

        for(i = 0; i<charLength; i++) {    
            if(letter === lWord[i]) {
              txt[i] = letter;
              misscount = 0;
            }  
            else {
              misscount++;
            }
            if(misscount === charLength) {
              misscount = 0;
              misses++;
              lostCheck();
              if(misses > 0 && misses < 8) { 
              return message.channel.send("You have made " + misses + "/8 mistakes!");
              }
            }
        }

        winCheck();
        outputTxt = txt.join(" ");
        if(misses < 8){
        return message.channel.send(outputTxt);
        }
}


    function winCheck() {
        succes = 0;

        for(i=0; i<charLength; i++) {
            if(txt[i] === lWord[i]) {
              succes++
            }
            else {
              succes = 0;
            }
          }

          if(succes === charLength) {
            succes = 0;
            for(i=0; i<charLength; i++) {
                if(txt[i] === lWord[i]) {
                succes++
                }   
                else {
                succes = 0;
                }
            } 

            if(succes === charLength && charLength > 0) {
                succes = 0;
                message.channel.send("You have won, the word was " + word + "!");
                console.log("\x1b[32m", "Player has guessed the word");
                console.log("\x1b[0m");
                reset();
            }
         }
    }


    function lostCheck() {
        if(misses === 8){
            message.channel.send("You lost, the word was " + word + "!");
            console.log("\x1b[31m", "Player lost the game");
            console.log("\x1b[0m");
            reset();
        }
    }


    function reset() {
        word = "";
        letter = "";
        lWord = [];
        charLength = 0;
        txt = [];
        outputTxt = "";
        misscount = 0;
        misses = 0;
        succes = 0;
        console.log("\x1b[35m", "Game has been reset");
        console.log("\x1b[0m");
        return message.channel.send("Game has been reset!");
    }

});


bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably happening because your trying to send `outputTxt` when it's empty (`''` or `' '`): Discord can only send a message when it has at least one non-space-like character.

You have to decide what to display when that string is empty. Let's say that if `outputTxt` is empty, you want the bot to send `'None'`: in this case you should edit `txtOutput()` and `tryletter()` to send the message in this way

```
return message.channel.send(outputTxt || "None");
```

The `||` means that if the first variable is `undefined` it will use the seconds: it's a shorthand form that can be useful.

```
// Extended form
if (outputTxt) return message.channel.send(outputTxt);
else return message.channel.send("None");

// Shorter form with ternary operator
return message.channel.send(outputTxt ? outputTxt : "None");

// Since we're only checking if that exists or not, you can write it directly as below
return message.channel.send(outputTxt || "None");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask you what the || does?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer with a little explanation :)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I appreciate it.